# Can the EFI System Partition be a logical partition on MBR disks?

Tags: partition, uefi, mbr

I'm finding a lot of information concerning the ESP inside GPT disks, but none about them being inside an MBR based disk as a logical partition.

The thing is, I don't want to convert my disk to GPT at all, and my PC don't have the CSM mode.

So, is it possible for the ESP to be a logical partition in an MBR disk ?

Comment: Curious why you don't want to use GPT? Or how you're booting currently if there is already an OS on the disk...

Answer (score 1):

The [specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202_6.pdf) in §5, starting on PDF page 165, gives the layout of an MBR partition table. It does not mention the extended partition, so UEFI does not support it.

Thus, according to the standard, would appear to be "no". (I confess to not having read all 2700 pages).

Comment: The ESP must have the boot flag on it, does it make a little chance that may make it a yes, or it doesn't mean anything ? (Sometimes it's even mounted as /boot/efi)

Comment: Because the standard is vague, I have a suspicion this is based more on the individual vendor's implementation of UEFI than it is the standard.  Take draft 802.11n for example:  Vendors didn't understand the provision that requires the AP to reduce its speed to wirelessG speeds if a single wirelessG device connected, so early Draft N devices ignored that line of the standard.